# What error did i make writing my recursive function using arrays?

Tags: arrays, c, recursion, function-definition

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int prod(int arr[], int n) {
    
    if (arr[n-1] < 0) {
        return 1;
    }

   return ((arr[n-1]) * (prod(arr[n-2] , n)));

}

int main( int argc, char* args[] ) {

    int arr[] = {2 , 3};

    printf("%d" , prod(arr , 2));
}
```

i keep getting pointer related errors but have no idea what to change, any help? The code is supposed to use the recursive function to get the product of all integers equal or over 0 in the array.

Comment: `arr[n-1] < 0` - when this condition will be satisfied?

Comment: `prod(arr[n-2] , n)` - this call is invalid. The function expects an array, but you give it the `[n-2]'s` element instead

Comment: Fix the compiler warnings instead of ignoring them.

Comment: In general, when making a recursive function, it is a good idea to start with a mathematical recursive rule you are trying to implement. For instance, a rule for array product will be: `prod(Arr, Len) = Arr[Len-1] * prod(Arr, Len-1)` for `Len > 0` and `prod(Arr, 0)=1`

Answer (score 2):

I guess the condition for termination of recursion should be:

```
if (n-1 < 0) {
        return 1;
}
```

It can be reformulated as:

```
if (n <= 0) {
        return 1;
}
```

What means that product of entries of empty array is **1**.
Moreover, expression that goes deeper should be:

```
return arr[n-1] * prod(arr , n - 1);
```

The final code could be:

```
int prod(int arr[], int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    return arr[n-1] * prod(arr, n - 1);
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I made this kind of mistake, figured out how to fix it anyway, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

There should be assignment in the prod function with something like this:-

```
n=n-1
```

You are not decreasing the value of n anywhere.

Comment: That's by no means the only major problem.

Comment: this is what I get trying to work with 0 focus, just figured out how dumb my mistakes are, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

This function is incorrect.

```
int prod(int arr[], int n) {
    
    if (arr[n-1] < 0) {
        return 1;
    }

   return ((arr[n-1]) * (prod(arr[n-2] , n)));

}
```

For starters this if statement

```
if (arr[n-1] < 0) {
    return 1;
}
```

does not make a sense.

It seems you mean

```
if ( n-1 < 0) {
    return 1;
}
```

In this expression

```
prod(arr[n-2] , n)
```

the first argument is a scalar object of the type `int`.  That is `arr[n-2]` is an element of an array. Also the second argument shall be decremented that is you have to use the expression `n - 1`.

But apart from this there are several other drawbacks.

For starters a product of elements of an array can be too big to fit in an object of the type `int`, You should use at least the type `long long int` as the return function type or maybe the float type `long double`.

Secondly as the array is not being changed within the function then the first parameter should have the qualifier const.

The user can pass as second argument the value `0`. In this case it will look strange that the function returns 1.

Thus the function should look at least like

```
long long int prod( const int arr[], size_t n ) 
{
    return n == 0 ? 0 : ( n == 1 ? arr[n-1] : arr[n-1] * prod( arr, n - 1 ) );         
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long int prod( const int arr[], size_t n ) 
{
    return n == 0 ? 0 : ( n == 1 ? arr[n-1] : arr[n-1] * prod( arr, n - 1 ) );         
}

int main(void) 
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    printf( "%lld\n" , prod( arr , sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr ) ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
3628800
```